# Youtube API. Get public live chat messages on different channel

Tags: youtube, chat, live

I have a trouble with getting live broadcast data (live chat messages) on a different channel. I found a few questions like that, they've been asked a couple of years ago and no solution found yet.

Is there an "official" way of getting public live chat messages via YouTube API without using such dirty ways like "loading page with help of Selenium and loading data into DOM"? In browser we can see them without logining as owner of the channel, I think there should be a way.